# Stream processors with multiple inputs and outputs as arrows

Tags: functional-programming, arrows

Reading John Hughes's [Generalising monads to arrows](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~rjmh/Papers/arrows.pdf), I understand that arrows can be used to represent and combine stream processors with a single input and a single output. It is also possible to represent multiple inputs and outputs using pairs, or using `ArrowChoice`.

However, using a pair means the input is a stream of pairs, which isn't enough to express processing streams that arrive at difference rates. `ArrowChoice` is able express that, but it "multiplexes" the two streams in a single one.

I'm looking for a way to combine streams with multiple inputs and multiple outputs, while still being able to distinguish between the case where the streams are multiplexed and the case of separate streams.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use the `These` type ([from here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/these-0.7.4/docs/Data-These.html)) which is defined as :

```
data These a b = This a | That b | These a b
```

This way you could express that you are receiving one stream, or the other, or both.

Comment: I'm not sure this solves my problem. I want to define a type that expresses a stream processor with 0 or more inputs and 0 or more outputs, and to be able to combine such processors similarly to what is done for single-input single-output processors using arrows.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Say you have a value of type `S (Either a b) (Either c d)`, you would like some way to be able to say whether it's a single stream processor  or a stream processor multiplexing two streams ?

Comment: My goal is to translate these stream processors into hardware for FPGA. For that I would like to be able to have two different constructs: a processor that accepts two streams, and a processor that accepts a single stream of an Either type. These can be translated into different hardware interfaces: two input FIFOs or one FIFO that is multiplexed.